# Best approach to load a dettached collection

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have a disconnected entity called "Establishment" which has a collection called "Locations".
What's the best approch to load this collection ?

I'm doing this:

```
var estab = new Establishment(){ ID = 1 };
Context.Establishment.Attach(estab);
Entry(estab).Collection(c => c.Locations).Load();
```

The problem is that, I'm testing this code on linqpad and it generates one sql text for each Location row (oh my!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable Lazy Loading
Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;